# Can someone help out with a better approach for this model

Tags: modeling, rendering, texturing, materials

I've tried to recreate this light in Blender. Maybe someone has a better and smarter approach to model this light.

My approach:

1. Create a sphere
2. Create a icosphere (small graves)
3. Icosphere displace modifier and texture
4. Create a Particle System for main sphere with Icosphere as *Render Object*.

[image: light Reference Image]

Comment: It looks like you are almost there ! For me the main problem is the lighting (Add an HDRI or an Area lamp on top of your object and tweak the light power) and the shading of your objects. You can use a darker blue on the shader of the particles and tweak it so that there is even more randomness on the scale of the icospheres. Also it will help if you build like 4 or 5 different pebbles by dragging the vertices of your icosphere and duplicating it, put it in a collection and instantiate that in the particle system

Comment: Is the object itself supposed to be a light emitter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create a material that would be a mix between *Voronoi* (*Distance to Edge* mode) and *Noise*, with a bit of Emission in order to fake translucency:

[image]

Then add a particle system with a collection of gravels. To vary the amount of each gravel, use the *Use Count* option:

[image]

Comment: or you could put all the gravel in one collection so you'd only have to make 1 particle system

Comment: how would you control the Number value if you want only 100 of the dark blue ones and 5000 of the light blue ones?

Comment: @moonboots To vary the ratios, check the 'Use Count' box in the Collection sub-panel.

Comment: oh ok, excellent, thanks for the info